# Permission in Chrome Extension Review

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Hi I a trying to launch a chrome extension and twice now it has been rejected after waiting 2 days stating that " The following permission(s) need not be requested for the methods/properties implemented by the item:"

and:
"How to rectify: Remove the above permission(s). The properties used by the items will continue to function even without requesting these permissions."

This has happened with the notifications permission and the tabs permission now. Can someone explain to me why this is occurring, why there are permission that I need to request to make it work locally by supposedly work without requestion it publicly, and also how to tell which ones are not needed?

Comment: It means your extension is not actually using the capability granted by these permissions e.g. the `tabs` permissions is necessary only to access a few properties of the tab object like `url` without requesting host permissions or using `activeTab`.

Comment: @WOxxOm this makes sense but what about the notifications permission. Locally when I remove it I get a background.js error that states nothing really but won't even allow the extension to run unless it has the notifications permission because I'm actually using the permission in the extension. I got a rejection saying that it will need to be removed

Comment: The reviewer has made a mistake. Try clicking the appeal link somewhere. Don't forget to provide a good concise description in "permission justfication" when submitting the extension.